# simple arithmetic question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Trying to solve the following inequality numerous times I've been reaching a wrong solution time after time: $$(x^2 - 4x +4)^x +  (2-x)^x <2 $$

after setting all the demands using systems of inequalities etc, I reached the solution:  $2<x<3 , x>3$ which is wrong.

how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

let $(2-x)^x = a$

$(a+2)(a-1)\lt 0$

$a \in (-2,1)$

$a \in (0,1)$

Comment: expressing all of this in terms of x is the tricky part

Comment: Just take the logarithm

Comment: Im not sure how to do that