# Basic Arithmetic Questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does one solve the following: [image] 
and also  $(x^2 - 4x +4)^x +  (2-x)^x <2 $ ? Should logarithms be used here or  there should be some algebraic method which takes into account the proprieties of $y=a^x$ , that is to be implemented?

Comment: hint for 2, let $y = (2-x)^x$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586851/simple-arithmetic-question

Answer (score 1):

HINTS: I assume that $x>0$. For the first problem, note that $x^{x^2+6}>x^{5x}$ if and only if $$\frac{x^{x^2+6}}{x^{5x}}>1\;,$$ and $$\frac{x^{x^2+6}}{x^{5x}}=x^{x^2+6-5x}=x^{x^2-5x+6}=x^{(x-2)(x-3)}\;.$$ If $x=2$ or $x=3$, that last exponent is $0$, and the expression is equal to $1$, which you don’t want. What are the other relevant possibilities?

- We could have $2<x<3$. In that case the exponent is negative; can the expression be greater than $1$ in that case?
- We could have $x>3$. Then the exponent is positive; is the expression greater than $1$?
- We could have $0<x<2$. Again the exponent is positive, but what happens now depends on whether $x>1$. Split this case into two smaller ones: $0<x\le 1$, and $1<x<2$.

For the second problem, note that $x^2-4x+4=(x-2)^2=(2-x)^2$. Let $u=2-x$; then your inequality becomes $(u^2)^x+u^x<2$, or $u^{2x}+u^x-2<0$. You can also write this as $(u^x)^2+u^x-2<0$ and think of the lefthand side as a quadratic in $u^x$. As such it factors: $(u^x-1)(u^x+2)<0$. You can solve that to get an inequality of the form $a<u^x<b$, i.e., $a<(2-x)^x<b$. Then, assuming that $2-x>0$ so that $(2-x)^x$ makes sense, you can use some of the ideas from the first problem to get an inequality for $x$.

Comment: I split into two cases: $ 0 <x<1$ or $ x>1 $ and kept interrogating from there...?

Comment: @Bak1139: I’m not sure exactly what you’re asking.

Comment: I meant that at the start I divided the possible ranges for x into theses two cases, and from there I kept interrogating what happens to the inequality

Comment: @Bak1139: For the first problem? Splitting at $x=1$ does turn out to be useful, but you also need the information from the exponent $(x-2)(x-3)$ in order to complete the problem. The split at $x=1$ actually affects only one of the main cases.

Answer (score 0):

Hints with logarithms:

$$\text{Assuming}\;\;1\neq x>0:\;\;\;\;x^{x^2+6}>x^{5x}\iff(x^2+6)\log x>5x\log x\iff$$

$$x^2+6>5x\iff (x-2)(x-3)>0\;\;\ldots\ldots$$

For number two: observe that $\;(2-x)^x\;$ is defined as a real number only for

$$\;2-x\ge0\iff x\le 2\;:$$

$$(x^2-4x+4)^x+(2-x)^x<2\iff(2-x)^{2x}+(2-x)^x<2$$

and putting $\;t=(2-x)^x\;$ we get

$$t^2+t-2<0\iff (t+2)(t-1)<0$$

But, for example

$$-2>t=(2-x)^x\;\;\text{there's no solution}\ldots\;\text{(why?)}$$

so we're left only with

$$1<t=(2-x)^x\iff x\log(2-x)>0\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

The first one can be solved by observation. Observe that in $x^{x^2+6}$ the exponent is $\ge6$ in the interval $(0,1)$ while the in $x^{5x}$ the exponent is $\le6$ and since the base of both the functions are equal so in $(0,1)$
$x^{5x}>x^{x^2+6}$
Similarly, in the interval $(1,\infty)$
$x^{5x}<x^{x^2+6}$
The second part can be re-written as,
$(x-2)^{2x}+(2-x)^x<2$
which has solution at $x=0,1$
It can be solved by taking logarithm of the function.